# AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock: doesn't stop

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, audio-player

**Description:**

Our app is a music player app.

[AVPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:]

We use this method to record the actual playing time of a user's song. Before it starts playing (and so does the single loop), we set the record time variable (playingSeconds) to 0 and keep +1 throughout the callback.

Normally, the method stops after a song is played.

But what we see in the background is that some users, a three-minute song, actually play for over 30,000 seconds (variable playingSeconds).

**Question:**

I just want to know what's causing the method to keep calling and not stop.

Or is there any other cause for this phenomenon?

Thanks!

```
@weakify(self);
self.playbackTimeObserver = [self.player addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(1.0, 1.0)
                                                                      queue:NULL
                                                                 usingBlock:^(CMTime time) {
    @strongify(self);
    if (!self.flagSeeking) {
        double ct = self.playerItem.currentTime.value / self.playerItem.currentTime.timescale;
        
        if (self.totalDuration == 0) {
            self.totalDuration = self.playerItem.duration.value / self.playerItem.duration.timescale;
            [self updateNowPlayingInfo:YES];
        }
        
        if (ct <= self.totalDuration && self.currentTime != ct && !self.isBuffering) {
            self.currentTime = ct;
        }
        
        if (self.state == BPAudioPlayerStatePlaying && !self.isBuffering) {
            if (ct <= 0) {
                self.playingSeconds = 0;
            } else {
                self.playingSeconds += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implicitly I read that you want to know, what goes wrong in you're code. It would, however, be helpful if you add a question to this post, so contributors can respond properly.

Comment: @MacUserT Thanks. I just want to know what's causing the method to keep calling and not stop. Or is there any other cause for this phenomenon?